# how to fetch other values along with distinct clause in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following postgres table workExperiences:

`id | userId | experience | isCurrentWorkplace
1  | 1      | xyz        | true
2  | 1      | abc        | true 
3  | 1      | wxy        | false 
4  | 2      | qwe        | false 
5  | 2      | xyz        | true 
6  | 3      | abc        | true`

I want to fetch unique userIds along with the id of the table where isCurrentlyWorkplace is set to true. As each user can have multiple records with isCurrentWorkPlace to true, i am getting duplicate records.

Basically, this is the result set that i want:

`id | userId | experience | isCurrentWorkplace
1  | 1      | xyz        | true
5  | 2      | xyz        | true 
6  | 3      | abc        | true`

The latest record of each user where isCurrentWorkplace is set to true.

The query works fine like this and returns distinct userIds:

```
select distinct ("userId") from "workExperiences" where "isCurrentWorkplace" = true;
```

but when i select id as well, i start to get duplicate records:

```
select distinct ("userId"), id from "workExperiences" where "isCurrentWorkplace" = true;
```

how can i achieve this?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate questions. I tried searching as well but could not find them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using row_number()

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by userid order by id) as rn
from "workExperiences" where "isCurrentWorkplace" = true
) A where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. i'll check this out as well . But please do check the duplicate answer as well. Its much more simpler in my opinion.